# AND between tokens in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

When I'm trying to search for a documents with such query (field indexed with Standard analyzer):

```
 "query": {
        "match": {
           "Book": "OG/44"
        }
    }
```

I've got terms 'OG' and '44' and the result set will contain results where could be either of these terms. What analyzer/tokenizer I should use to get results when only both of terms are present?

Comment: Maybe you need to escape slash in query or when indexing value?

Comment: But that would be one token isn't it?

Comment: Yep. Do you need to have two tokens and query for them both ?

Comment: It depends, I don't know if I will get result like 'OG/44/13' with escaped query. I can't change  client code radically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set **operator** in match query (by default it is *or*)

```
"query": {
    "match": {
       "Book": {
           "query": "OG/44",
           "operator" : "and"
       }
    }
}
```

You have two tokens because *standard* analyzer tokenized them by slash, so if you need not this behaviour you can escape it

Comment: I can change analyzer in any moment. I'd like to avoid introduction of new operators in query. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: If "OG/44" must be parsed as one token, you can use **whitespaсe** analyzer to tokenize items by space

Comment: If you do not want to tokenize string, use **keyword** analyzer

Comment: See my comment in question, with **whitespace** and **keyword** I won't be able to find fields like 'OG/44/13'.

Comment: So as I understand, you want to find "OG/44/13" by quering "OG/44" ?

Comment: Yes, now it returns anything containing either 'OG' or '44'.

Comment: And there can be any tokens. So the only way to do this is to use **operator**, because this kind of query can not be resolved by tokenizing.

Comment: In that case I will change the calling contract, thanks. It works like a charm.